# Dependency injection with constructor not working

Tags: ninject

I have the following code

```
SmtpSection smtpsection = 
       (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");

EmailSettings emailSettings = new EmailSettings
        {
            WriteAsFile = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""] ?? "false"),
            ServerPort = smtpsection.Network.Port,
            Username = smtpsection.Network.UserName,
            Password = smtpsection.Network.Password,
            UseSsl = smtpsection.Network.EnableSsl
        };

kernel.Bind<IEmailRepository>().To<EmailRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("settings", emailSettings);
```

and

```
public class EmailSettings 
{
        public string MailToAddress = "test@Test.com";
        public string MailFromAddress = "test@test.com";
        public bool UseSsl = true;
        public string Username = "";
        public string Password = "";
        public string ServerName = "";
        public int ServerPort = 587;
        public bool WriteAsFile = false;
        public string FileLocation = @"C:\sports_store_emails";
}

public class EmailController : Controller
{
        private IEmailRepository emailRepository;
        private EmailSettings emailSettings;

        public EmailController(IEmailRepository emailRepository, EmailSettings settings)
        {
            this.emailRepository = emailRepository;
            this.emailSettings = settings;
        }
}

public class EmailRepository : RepositoryBase<EmailEnquiry>, IEmailRepository
{
    public EmailRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        : base(databaseFactory)
    {
    }
}

public interface IEmailRepository : IRepository<EmailEnquiry>
{
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);      
        void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        T GetById(long Id);
        T GetById(string Id);
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}
```

For some reason the arguments for NInject the settings are not getting passed in. Does anyone know why this is. settings is using all the values from inside `EmailSettings` and not what is passed in from NInject?

Comment: Where is the implementation of `EmailRepository`?

Comment: You must pass `IDatabaseFactory` to your `EmailRepository` constructor instead of `EmailSettings`.

Comment: i already have this line in ninject   kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>();

Comment: protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        {
            DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
            dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you already have configured binding for `IDatabaseFactory` you can create `EmailRepository` as

```
var emailRepository = kernel.Get<EmailRepository>();
```

**UPDATE**

To initialize instance of `EmailController` you can just use

```
var emailController =
          new EmailController(kernel.Get<EmailRepository>(), settings);
```

Comment: I am trying to pass in a Constructor with dependency injection how would i do this for EmailController(IEmailRepository emailRepository, EmailSettings settings)

Comment: what do i add to ninject to pass in settings then?

Comment: No extra configuration is needed over that already you have. `Ninjcet` already know how to resolve interface `IDatabaseFactory` and can create instance of `EmailRepository`.

Comment: how about settings tho the parameter

Comment: i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: kernel.Bind<IEmailRepository>().To<EmailRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("settings", emailSettings); from my example above does not pass in the email settings via the constructor so for example Username is null. the settings are not getting passed through with withcontructorargument function

Comment: Have you tried the code from updated answer? You needn't create `EmailController` via `Ninject`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39604/discussion-between-matthew-chambers-and-hamlet-hakobyan)